# Case sensitive provider makes login fail

Tags: security, symfony, authentication

I have set my login process using security.yml

```
form_login:
                login_path: /a/login
                check_path: /login_check
                username_parameter: inputUsername
                password_parameter: inputPassword
                provider: users
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                success_handler: ng.security.authentication_handler
                failure_handler: ng.security.authentication_handler
            remember_me:
                key:      "%secret%"
                lifetime: 31536000 # 365 days in seconds
                path:     /
                domain:   ~
            pattern:   ^/
            anonymous: ~
            logout:
                path:   /logout
                target: /
```

my provider is  :

```
providers:
    users:
        mongodb: {class: ng\Nundle\Document\Users, property: lname}
```

lname is the lower case field of name.
Now if the user inputs something with an upper case , he won't succeed in login.
How can I turn every input he's making to lowercase ? 
thanks !

Comment: there is this silly solution : use CSS in the input to turn everything lowercase. but it's SILLY